# How to remove md-dialog's background completely?

Tags: css, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-material, mddialog

I'm using AngularJs with Angular-Material and Jquery-ui for creating a floating and draggable  dialog window - i was manage to create what i want - the problem is that the md-dialog has a container div (md-dialog-container) that stretched all over the page - and prevent pressing any buttons outside the dialog.

I wonder how i can disable the background in some way to be able to press any button in the page when the dialog is open.

I've set the md-dialog 'hasBackdrop' option to false - i guess it wasn't enough.

```
let dialogOptionsObj = {
  controller: 'DialogController',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-tpl.html',
  parent: angular.element(document.body),
  panelClass: 'myClass',
  hasBackdrop: false, // this is what cancels the gray background
  autoWrap: false,
  clickOutsideToClose: false,
  preserveScope: true,
  fullscreen: false,
};
```

I've found that if the md-dialog container is completely removed (md-dialog-container) and the md-dialog is appending directly to the document.body then it's working - i'm looking for a better solution since i want it to be with less Jquery as possible.

[Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/wqHzCLOciiXrel29?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the CSS property `pointer-events`.

If you want the click to "go through" the element, the value to use is `none`.

So you juste have to add the following CSS :

```
.dialog-basic-size{
   pointer-events: auto;
}

.md-dialog-container , .md-scroll-mask {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/I7XRwxpNZMqNHemo)

You can read more about the pointer-event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: Thanks -  i;m checking it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you chose not the best direction.

> I wonder how i can disable the background in some way to be able to press any button in the page when the dialog is open.

It is like: *"I want a steel box with four doors, so I decided to buy a car and remove the wheels and engine."*

You try to break the concept of dialog ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_box)). It is designed to avoid all event propagation a.e. clicks outside the dialog box to make a focus of users on specific information like alert, warning, and so on.

---

> ... creating a floating and draggable ...

You have enough libraries for Angularjs, that work with divs (`position: absolute`) just google it :)

Comment: You kind of right - since i didn't found any libraries that do what i needed then i did have to "force" the dialog directive to my needs - which are - reuse the directive and the most important thing - use dynamic templates... if you'll break down my requirements - i guess you'll find some sense in my direction....i want to create a component for floating dialog with angularjs - with less jquery as i can..... if you are familiar with any other library - please mention it - it would be a very big help - thanks.

Comment: @RoyBarOn what is the purpose of your dialog, drag and drop? or only drag?

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/hD1A7p/.  or https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/iqqe7I or very simple directive: http://jsfiddle.net/pzvc1u3q/